# badge swipe group record

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have tried self joins and attempted to read the next record and compare machinename and value..but the SQL db has no id numbers and then the data comes up inconsistently grouped based on how I sort..Can someone lend some assistance.  I have no SQL in front at the moment..

```
datetime            machinename value
02/02/2015 07:12:33 machine1    11111
02/02/2015 07:22:33 machine1    11111
02/02/2015 08:09:12 machine8    22222
02/02/2015 08:45:35 machine2    22222
02/02/2015 09:12:33 machine8    22222
02/02/2015 09:13:15 machine8    22222
02/02/2015 08:48:33 machine2    11111
02/02/2015 08:48:37 machine2    11111
02/02/2015 08:48:56 machine2    11111
02/02/2015 10:22:12 machine7    33333
02/02/2015 10:55:12 machine2    11111
02/02/2015 12:25:23 machine3    33333
02/02/2015 13:01:05 machine3    33333
02/02/2015 23:46:23 machine3    11111
02/03/2015 01:01:05 machine3    11111
```

expected outcome

```
> datetime start       datetime end         machinename        value
> 02/02/2015 07:12:33  02/02/2015 07:22:33  machine1           11111
> 02/02/2015 08:09:12  NULL                 machine8           22222
> 02/02/2015 08:45:35  NULL                 machine2           22222
> 02/02/2015 09:12:33  02/02/2015 09:13:15  machine8           22222
> 02/02/2015 08:48:33  02/02/2015 08:48:37  machine2           11111
> 02/02/2015 08:48:56  NULL                 machine2           11111
> 02/02/2015 10:22:12  NULL                 machine7           33333
> 02/02/2015 10:55:12  NULL                 machine2           11111
> 02/02/2015 12:25:23  02/02/2015 13:01:05  machine3           33333
> 02/02/2015 23:46:23  02/03/2015 01:01:05  machine3           11111
```

A person could swipe multiple time in/out within a few seconds such as this:

```
02/02/2015 08:48:33  02/02/2015 08:48:37  machine2           11111
02/02/2015 08:48:56  NULL                 machine2           11111
```

or have one swipe if they leave a machine and go swipe at another machine.
such as:

```
02/02/2015 08:48:56  NULL                 machine2           11111
```

Comment: What database are you using? (oracle, sql server, mysql, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How do you define a startdate vs endtime? Is that the 11111, 22222, 33333 column? I feel there will be some windowed functions, but yes, knowing what database server you are using would be a good start!

Comment: I am using SQL server.  The "column" name is value for "11111,22222,33333".

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? SQL Server 2012+ have `LEAD` and `LAG` functions that may help with this type of query,

Comment: SQL Server 2012..  I tried the lead & lag..Keep getting "'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name."  I have the analytic add on installed.

Comment: running 2008 that is reason for being unable to use "Lead" or "Lag"!..

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
select 
  stamp as starttime,
  (select min(stamp)
   from table1 as t1a
   where t1a.machinename = t1.machinename
   and t1a.id = t1.id
   and t1a.stamp > t1.stamp
   and t1a.stamp < dateadd(mi,15,t1.stamp)
   ) as endtime,
  machinename, 
  id
from table1 as t1
where stamp <>  (
  select max(stamp)  
  from table1 as t1b
  where t1b.machinename = t1.machinename
  and t1b.id = t1.id
  and t1b.stamp > dateadd(mi,-15,t1.stamp)
  )
```

Fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c82cf/11

Adjust time in seconds as required.

**EDIT:** I left out the machinename. Fixed.

**EDIT2:** Revised to remove starttime when it was used as an endtime.  Changed time period to 15 minutes to reflect test data. Fiddle revised.

**EDIT3:**

Perhaps I misunderstood exactly how the matching was supposed to happen. This might work better:

```
with cte as ( 
  select 
  stamp as starttime,
  (select stamp 
   from table1 as t1a
   where 
          t1a.machinename = t1.machinename
      and t1a.id = t1.id 
   and stamp = 
  (select min(stamp)
   from table1 as t1aa
   where t1aa.stamp > t1.stamp
   )) as endtime,
  machinename, 
  id
from table1 as t1
) 
select *
from cte
where starttime not in (select endtime from cte where endtime is not null)
```

Which is in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c82cf/63

Results:

```
starttime                     endtime                       machinename    id
February, 02 2015 07:12:33    February, 02 2015 07:22:33    machine1    11111
February, 02 2015 08:09:12    (null)                        machine8    22222
February, 02 2015 08:45:35    (null)                        machine2    22222
February, 02 2015 09:12:33    February, 02 2015 09:13:15    machine8    22222
February, 02 2015 08:48:33    February, 02 2015 08:48:37    machine2    11111
February, 02 2015 10:22:12    (null)                        machine7    33333
February, 02 2015 10:55:12    (null)                        machine2    11111
February, 02 2015 12:25:23    February, 02 2015 13:01:05    machine3    33333
February, 02 2015 23:46:23    February, 03 2015 01:01:05    machine3    11111
```

Comment: Will give it a try in morning when I can access my Db.  Thank You

Comment: Check the fiddle to see if it gives you what you want.

Comment: running select 
  stamp as starttime,
  (select min(stamp)
   from table1 as t1a
   where t1a.machinename = t1.machinename
   and t1a.id = t1.id
   and t1a.stamp > t1.stamp
   and t1a.stamp < dateadd(s,120,t1.stamp)
   ) as endtime,
  machinename, 
  id
from table1 as t1
it does not work.  If I remove the dateadd line it does but leaves a second line after it correlates the data.    IE this line "('2015-02-02 07:22:33', 'machine1', 11111)" is a dupe.  See you fiddle afte you highlight the dateadd line.  Thank You

Comment: Tried new fiddle .  Not returning data correct.  "data missing"  see "February, 02 2015 23:46:23" to 2015-02-03 01:01:05..  I think the issue lie with the dateadd function in qry.